# I dont understand this "inefficient jQuery usage"

Tags: jquery, optimization

PyCharm says this about the following code: "inefficient jQuery usage" without giving any valuable explanation. I dont know how I could make this efficient:

```
$('#popup-key input:eq(18)').val(key.labelcolor);
$('#popup-key input:eq(19)').val(key.color);
```

Same for this code:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    var value = $('#popup-key input:eq(' + (i * 2) + ')').val();
    var size = $('#popup-key input:eq(' + (i * 2 + 1) + ')').val() || defaultSettings.f;
    if (value.trim() != '') {
        clone.labels.push(new Label(value, inputToPositions[i], size));
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens. You look up all the inputs one time to get one. Than throw it all away. Than next time you look up all the inputs again to find another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store a collection to avoid so much dom searching for the same selector group each time

```
var $input = $('#popup-key input');

$input.eq(18).val(key.labelcolor);
$input.eq(19).val(key.color);

//etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making a lot of similar queries and using the `:eq()` selector a lot. It is more efficient to make a single query and then iterate over the results. This is because each time you query, it has to parse the selector string and then check the entire document for elements that match that selector.

```
$('#popup-key input').each(function(el, i) {
    $(el).val();
});
```

By only doing the query once, the `each()` function will already know what elements it needs to deal with and not have to do any unnecessary selection. Any time you can eliminate redundant queries, you'll make your scripts more efficient.